# Get the output of a formula from a function

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 columns that I want to multiply and then add the result with the rows below. The thing is the user can add a row so it has to be dynamic. If there is a row F that appears the function has to add the multiplication of the new row.

[image: example :]

```
Public Function sum_multiply(z As Range, decal As Integer)
dim cel As Range, str As String

Set z = Range(z, z.End(xlDown))

For Each cel In z
    str = str & "(" & cel.Address & "*" & cel.Offset(, decal).Address & ")"
    If cel.Offset(1) <> "" Then str = str & "+"
Next cel
sum_multiply = "=" & str
 
End Function
```

I have no problem to create the custom formula, it's the moment where I need it to be applied that gives me trouble.
The idea is that I use this function in a cell and that it returns the output of the formula in it.
However I always end up with a #Value

I tried to set the function as a range :

```
Public Function sum_multiply(z As Range, decal As Integer) as range

set sum_multiply.formula = "=" & str
```

Also as an integer but it doesn't work. I'm now doubting if I can apply a formula with a function.

Comment: Does the solution need to use vba? Can it be regular formula such as sumproduct or lamda and reduce?

Comment: If I use the classic formula in excel, it doesn't add the new lines in the formula. that's why I'm trying with a custom function. But if there's a tweek that I didn't think of, I would gladly take it.

Comment: Make your data into a table. New rows will automatically be included assuming you refer to the table columns.

Comment: If you extend the range one row below your data when the user adds a row under the data it will extend the range in the formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got 3 options:

[image]

**OPTION 1**: As suggested in the comments and, to be honest, **it's the best one indeed** would be creating a table (a listobject) so ranges will be dynamic

In cell F10 my formula is:

`=SUMPRODUCT(Tabla1[Field 2],Tabla1[Field 3])`

Piece of cake and easy to implement and will work great.

**OPTION 2:** With complex function OFFSET you can manage to create dynamic ranges but this approach is not really good if you don't know what are you doing and other data in rows below may interfere (notice the formula uses just the rows 18:98 so nothing can be there). Formula in cell E19:

`=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(B18,0,0,COUNTA(B18:B98)),OFFSET(C18,0,0,COUNTA(C18:C98)))`

**OPTION 3:** Use a volatile UDF in VBA. I'm using this on cell  H10:

`=sum_multiply(B4)`.

Code of UDF:

```
Public Function sum_multiply(ByVal topLeftCell As Range) As Double
Application.Volatile

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim LR As Long

LR = topLeftCell.End(xlDown).Row

With topLeftCell.Parent
    Set rng1 = .Range(topLeftCell, topLeftCell.Offset(LR - topLeftCell.Row))
    Set rng2 = .Range(topLeftCell.Offset(0, 1), topLeftCell.Offset(LR - topLeftCell.Row, 1))
End With

sum_multiply = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(rng1, rng2)

End Function
```

All of them work perfectly if I add new data at bottom row:

[image]

Use option 1 with no doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I presented a simplistic version of what I have to do and I can't use a table format. I got a bit fast and didn't search well Excel's functions but SumProduct helped to get what I want thank you.